# scipy spherical harmonics giving nan+nanj

Tags: python, scipy

In my current code I need a function into which I can put (l,m,theta,phi) or in scipy's notation (n,m,theta,phi) and it will output the value of a spherical harmonic for those parameters. scipy's sph_harm function worked perfectly for this until trying for higher l and m. For example if I use l=88, m=85, theta=0, phi=pi/2 (i.e. sph_harm(85,88,0,np.pi/2)) then the outputted value is nan+nanj.

Any ideas how to avoid this problem? I need to be able to put in any reasonable (|m|

Comment: I'm not an expert but aren't those polynomials? And aren't l and m somehow related to the degree? Maybe these values are more off the scale than you think. Anyway, everything else failing you could try and brute-force it with [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/doc/1.0.0/functions/orthogonal.html#spherical-harmonics)

Comment: See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7778

Comment: You are correct that there is a polynomial hidden inside the sph_harm function. I know that these sort of numbers can be solved because when doing calculations of wavefunctions whatever principle quantum number N used l numbers of n-1 will have to be used at some point and I have seen some of these calculations done with N up far above 100 for Rydberg atom/molecules. I will consider a brute force method but hope to avoid it. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Ah that GitHub page looks exactly like my problem, I will check it out. Cheers